# Laravel 8 で 419 PAGE EXPIRED が出るようになりました

Tags: docker, laravel

Laravel 8.83.27で開発中のプロジェクトです。
以前は普通に動いていたのですが、POSTすると419が出るようになってしまいました。

#### 動かなくなる前にやったこと

##### 1点目

パフォーマンス改善のためにdocker-syncを使おうとしたのですが動かなくて辞めました。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/docker-sync-1.0.5/lib/docker-sync/sync_strategy/unison.rb:233:in `block in start_container': Failed to start unison container in time, try to increase max_attempt (currently 10) in your configuration. See https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/wiki/2.-Configuration for more informations (RuntimeError)
```

docker-sync.ymlに `max_attempt:100` を書いても改善されなかったので `docker-sync clean` して消しました。

##### 2点目

`php artisan config:cache` を開発環境なのにしてしまった。
これのせいな気がしたのですべてを白紙に戻すためにローカルもDokcerコンテナも全て消してgitでクローンしなおしましたが直らず。

#### 試した・確認したこと

1. @csrfが入っているか
2. ブラウザのキャッシュ・coockieクリア
3. Docker内ファイルのパーミッションが制限されていないか

App\Http\Kernel.php内の

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

をコメントアウトしたら一回ログインはできてるようですが、
ログインユーザー認証がうまくいっていないのかログイン画面に戻ってきてしまいます。
完成間際なのでログイン認証を今から外すことは正直手間ですし複数人でgit管理して開発しているのであまりいじりたくない気持ちもあります。
（ログイン認証周りはlaravel/jetstream,sanctumを使っています。）

エラーログも出ないのでどうすればいいか分かりません。
何か教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: ちなみに、 `config:cache` で生成されたキャッシュファイルは `config:clear` できえます。

Answer (score 0):

.envの下記の一文をコメントアウトしたら動きました…

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=".http://localhost"
```

axiosでAPIを使うときに追記したものでしたがすっかり忘れてました。